# Reference request: When is a conic birationally equivalent to the projective line?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a reference which contains the proof of the following theorem:

"A conic $C$ defined over the field $\mathbb{F}$ is birationally equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^{1}(\mathbb{F})$ if and only if $C(\mathbb{F})\neq\emptyset.$"

Google didn't seem to help me too much (but maybe I've been shortsighted!).

Comment: For what definition of conic?

Comment: I mean is "conic" a variety defined by a homogeneous degree 2 equation in 3 variables (when irreducible and smooth).

Comment: yes, indeed! :)

Comment: See Prop 19.3.1 of Vakil's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the proof is this:

Let $P$ be a rational point on $C$. Then look at all the lines through $P$. Each such line intersect $C$ in one more point.

This lets us define a rational map $\mathbb P^1 \to C$ since lines are parametrized by $\mathbb P^1$ (it is rational because the tangent line only meets $C$ at one point). The map is well defined and injective by Bezout.

Answer (score 1):

'Diophantine Geometry: An Introduction', by Silverman and Hindry, contains a proof in section A.4.3 (Page 74). A few minor steps are skipped, but it should be fairly easy to follow.